# How to give name for undefined object key which generate by lodash groupBy()?

Tags: javascript, json, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

The result of lodash `groupBy()` gives `{ "student": [], "undefined": [] }`.

```
const splittedData = _.groupBy(datas, 'type');
```

Is it possible to give name for the key `undefined` ?

```js
const datas = [
  {
    _id: "5ea2ecbde53c090b4ba4fa12",
    firstName: "Dillon",
    surname: "Mclaughlin",
    guid: "a727438f-4ddc-4422-af4a-c7396fda73c3",
    isActive: true,
    balance: "$3,331.33",
    picture: "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    age: 37,
    type: "student"
  },
  {
    _id: "5ea2ecbd067a8ad1cb1f9e62",
    firstName: "Fleming",
    surname: "Austin",
    guid: "e228bbea-ef6b-4709-995c-bf485fa3665c",
    isActive: true,
    balance: "$1,869.92",
    picture: "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    age: 35
  },
  {
    _id: "5ea2ecbd0d1a074b255a1349",
    firstName: "Kaufman",
    surname: "Alford",
    guid: "176fb7fe-b7bc-4574-8887-4252a042b24a",
    isActive: true,
    balance: "$2,163.34",
    picture: "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    age: 29,
    type: "student"
  },
  {
    _id: "5ea2ecbd1162ee44119aa0d3",
    firstName: "Sykes",
    surname: "Petty",
    guid: "92b13963-7d32-469c-be80-c88728a7842a",
    isActive: false,
    balance: "$2,728.46",
    picture: "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    age: 37
  },
  {
    _id: "5ea2ecbd297854a2f85909a4",
    firstName: "Stuart",
    surname: "Pickett",
    guid: "322031f9-1a71-44ae-b1cf-cbe7430b78b6",
    isActive: false,
    balance: "$1,725.25",
    picture: "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    age: 25,
    type: "student"
  },
  {
    _id: "5ea2ecbd6ef4a9bee37a223a",
    firstName: "Berg",
    surname: "Hewitt",
    guid: "ab05bed9-29e4-4570-aa12-fead954417b0",
    isActive: false,
    balance: "$2,935.72",
    picture: "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    age: 31
  }
];

const splittedData = _.groupBy(datas, 'type');
console.log(splittedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/athimannil/pen/pojePYK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working link
https://codepen.io/sudheer-ranga/pen/LYpWLLZ

If you want to filter by only students

```
const grouped = _(datas)
  .filter(object => _.has(object, 'type'))
  .groupBy('type')
  .value();

console.log(grouped);
```

If you want to group students and non students

```
const nonStudents = _.groupBy(datas, object => _.get(object, 'type', 'no_type'))

console.log(nonStudents)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `_.get()` function to get the `type` or supply a fallback value if `type` is `undefined`:

```js
const datas = [{"_id":"5ea2ecbde53c090b4ba4fa12","firstName":"Dillon","surname":"Mclaughlin","guid":"a727438f-4ddc-4422-af4a-c7396fda73c3","isActive":true,"balance":"$3,331.33","picture":"http://placehold.it/32x32","age":37,"type":"student"},{"_id":"5ea2ecbd067a8ad1cb1f9e62","firstName":"Fleming","surname":"Austin","guid":"e228bbea-ef6b-4709-995c-bf485fa3665c","isActive":true,"balance":"$1,869.92","picture":"http://placehold.it/32x32","age":35},{"_id":"5ea2ecbd0d1a074b255a1349","firstName":"Kaufman","surname":"Alford","guid":"176fb7fe-b7bc-4574-8887-4252a042b24a","isActive":true,"balance":"$2,163.34","picture":"http://placehold.it/32x32","age":29,"type":"student"},{"_id":"5ea2ecbd1162ee44119aa0d3","firstName":"Sykes","surname":"Petty","guid":"92b13963-7d32-469c-be80-c88728a7842a","isActive":false,"balance":"$2,728.46","picture":"http://placehold.it/32x32","age":37},{"_id":"5ea2ecbd297854a2f85909a4","firstName":"Stuart","surname":"Pickett","guid":"322031f9-1a71-44ae-b1cf-cbe7430b78b6","isActive":false,"balance":"$1,725.25","picture":"http://placehold.it/32x32","age":25,"type":"student"},{"_id":"5ea2ecbd6ef4a9bee37a223a","firstName":"Berg","surname":"Hewitt","guid":"ab05bed9-29e4-4570-aa12-fead954417b0","isActive":false,"balance":"$2,935.72","picture":"http://placehold.it/32x32","age":31}];

const splittedData = _.groupBy(datas, o => _.get(o, 'type', 'not a student') );

console.log(splittedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an `iteratee` function that uses the desired default value if there was no `type` in the object at all:

```js
const splittedData = _.groupBy(datas, o => 'type' in o ? o.type : 'unknown');
```

The difference between this and later "renaming" the `"undefined"` in the result is that the "renaming" option would not be able to differentiate between `type: "undefined"` and no type at all, while this one does.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just copy the 'undefined' value to something else and delete the original.

```js
const splittedData = _.groupBy(datas, 'type');
splittedData["default-type"] = splittedData["undefined"];
delete splittedData["undefined"];
```

Comment: Actually that would clash with `type: "undefined"`. The way to solve that would be to map the input array to objects whose `type` gets the chosen default value if it was `undefined` (not `"undefined"`)